# Cant figure out how to get a method to run async

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a trackbar follow an mp3 while playing. I set up my method as a task however it locks up my application for the duration of the song. Any help is appreciated!

```
public void update(TrackBar t, AudioFileReader r)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
        {
            t.Maximum = (int) 
            (Math.Ceiling(r.TotalTime.TotalSeconds));
            t.Value = (int)(r.Position / 
            r.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond);

        });
    }

Task.Run(()=>update(trackBar2, audioFile));
```

Comment: does your audio player have any events - thats when you should update the trackbar

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply! If you mean events as in buttons and such the update method is called as a task in my play button event method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this async await, to make your task asynchronous.

```
public async Task updateAsync(TrackBar t, AudioFileReader r) {
     await Task.Run((()=>update(t,r));
}

public void update(TrackBar t, AudioFileReader r)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
    {
        t.Maximum = (int) 
        (Math.Ceiling(r.TotalTime.TotalSeconds));
        t.Value = (int)(r.Position / 
        r.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond);
    });
}

updateAsync(trackBar2, audioFile);
```